# Spatial Join to count points in polygons in lat/lon in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have a table, called `pets`, with lats and lng coordinates and variables and a table that was created by uploading a shapefile, called `city`, with columns `left, right, top, bottom, lat, lng,` and  `geom.`

```
    lat    lng   cats  dogs
   -59.4   42.1   2     0
   -58.1   44.3   1     1
   -59.7   43.6   0     3 
   -59.8   42.0   2     1
```

I'm wondering how I would construct a query that will sum up the number of cats and dogs within each boundary. Usually I would do a spatial join in QGIS but my dataset is too large and it crashes before successfully joining the two.

I am pretty familiar with QGIS and Postgres, but very new to PostGIS. I've constructed a query but unsuccessful in getting the answer I needed:

```
select sum(pets.dogs)
from pets, city
WHERE ST_Within(pets.dogs, city.geom);
```

How do I do this in PostGIS?

Comment: Is the city.geom in WGS84?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking as hypothesis that:

- city.geom is in EPSG:4326
- lat, lng in pets table can also be taken as EPSG:4326
- That you want to sum the number of cats and dogs that are in each geometry of the table city
- That the geoms in table city do not overlap or if overlaps you don't care to count two times the pets
- city has a pk called gid
- You are not interested in the points outside the boundaries of the cities

The query that must be built should take the following into account:

Convert lat,lng coordinates into postgis geometries in 4326

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat), 4326) FROM pets;
```

The you must build a query that sums the cats and dogs on each geom:

```
SELECT gid, sum(cats), sum(dogs) FROM city c, pets_with_geom p WHERE ST_Within(p.geom, c.geom) GROUP BY c.gid
```

To build the full query we use a CTE

```
WITH pets_with_geom AS(
  SELECT cats, dogs, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat), 4326) as geom FROM pets
)
SELECT gid, sum(cats), sum(dogs) FROM city c, pets_with_geom p WHERE ST_Within(p.geom, c.geom) GROUP BY c.gid
```

Using this test data:

```
CREATE TABLE pets (
  gid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  lat double precision,
  lng double precision,
  dogs int,
  cats int
);

INSERT INTO pets (lat, lng, dogs, cats) VALUES (0.647, -0.977, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO pets (lat, lng, dogs, cats) VALUES (0.673, -0.245, 4, 4);
INSERT INTO pets (lat, lng, dogs, cats) VALUES (0.520, -0.789, 2, 2);

CREATE TABLE city (
  gid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  geom geometry(MULTIPOLYGON, 4326)
);

INSERT INTO city (gid, geom) VALUES (1, '0106000020E610000001000000010300000001000000050000008ACE1C2D1BE2F0BF64DF23728270E73F431C149D395AE6BF64DF23728270E73F1120C30FD548E6BFFE9B075EE536DD3F715074E668D9F0BF6294A978AE59DD3F8ACE1C2D1BE2F0BF64DF23728270E73F');
INSERT INTO city (gid, geom) VALUES (2, '0106000020E61000000100000001030000000100000005000000F05CB33A8C32B5BFC2C45A4F42EAE73F40B81BFB1E91B3BFA6C93BBE2E66DC3F189726EFF8BAD8BFB2EF113941B8DB3FB49E84D42F98D8BF2CD067A714B6E73FF05CB33A8C32B5BFC2C45A4F42EAE73F');
INSERT INTO city (gid, geom) VALUES (3, '0106000020E61000000100000001030000000100000005000000DC2985EDAD40DF3FF4C0ABDCA6FBE73F1A7EA846B208E03F42D199A36543DC3FD0B2210E8ACECC3F16E8B3530ADBDB3F200E8ACE1C2DCB3F8AB59E84D42FE83FDC2985EDAD40DF3FF4C0ABDCA6FBE73F');
```

You can get this results:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ gid │ sum │ sum │
├─────┼─────┼─────┤
│   2 │   4 │   4 │
│   1 │   3 │   3 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
(2 rows)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I figured out but for some reason, the error I keep getting is that `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` where the ST_MakePoint function is....thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the CREATE TABLE sentence of pets. ST_MakePoint expects the parameters to be in double precision, you can cast it with:ST_MakePoint(lng::double precision, lat::double precision)

Comment: I tested this query out `select ST_setSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng::double precision, lat::double precision),4326) FROM pets;` and got the following error `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision:`

Comment: Paste your CREATE TABLE pets sentence and a couple of INSERT INTO pets. It seems that your columns lat and lng doesn't have a correct format.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE pets (
lat double precision,
lng double precision,
dogs int,
cats int);`

Comment: I also tried adding in the `::double precision` to the lats and lng and I get the error `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision:`

Comment: I update my posts with a working example. Please edit your post and paste your "real" create table definition. I think the problem is there

Comment: Awesome, I love how comprehensive your answer is. Thanks!